# Classify the singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Take the function $f(z)=\cos\frac{1}{z}$.
It's not defined at $0$, but how exactly do I classify that point?

If I multiply it by $z$, the limit at $0$ is $0$ so I could define the function $g$ as $g(z)=z\cos\frac{1}{z}$ for $z\neq0$ and $g(0)=0$. Now $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z}$. But the definition of a pole says $g$ can't be zero at the pole.

What is that point then?

Comment: limit of z.cos(1/z) as z goes to 0 is not 0. Even if we multiply cos(1/z) by any positive power of z and take the limit does not exist. 0 is an essential singularity point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singularity at $z=0$ is neither removable, nor a pole, hence (by definition) an essential singularity. Also observe what happens to $zg(z)$ as you approach $0$ from the imaginary axis.

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't sandwich it.